# Powershell - If file not in attachment

Tags: powershell

Using the below code how do I put a check in place that if the $FileName doesn't exist in the email then fail.

Ideally I want something like this -

```
Write-Host "Attachment $FileName does not exist for download."; exit 1
```

But I'm not sure where to put it in the code.

```
    $EmailwithAttachments = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage]::Bind($service, $Email.Id, $emailProps)
    Foreach ($File in $EmailwithAttachments.Attachments) {
        If ($File.name -eq $FileName) {
            Try {
                    #Just to be safe, remove any invaild characters from the attachment name
                    $FileName = $File.name -replace ("[{0}]" -f ([RegEx]::Escape([String][System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars())))
                    #Current can't handle Emails that are attacments, so we skip them
                    Write-Host "Attachment $FileName exists for download."
                    If ($File.contenttype -eq $null) {
                            Write-Warning "Attachment is an email, skipping"
                            $EMLAttachment = $TRUE
                            continue
                    }
                    Else {
                        $EMLAttachment = $FALSE
                    }
                    $File.load($SavePath + "\\" + $FileName)
                    If (($FileName -like "*.zip") -and $UnZipFiles) {$ZipFileNames += $SavePath + "\"+ $FileName}
            }
            Catch {
                Send-ErrorReport -Subject "Attachment save path cannot be accessed" -body "Please verify the following path <B>$SavePath</B><BR>Full Error:<BR> $_" -HaltScript
            }
        }
    }
    If ($UnZipFiles) {
    Try {
            $shell = new-object -com shell.application
            $Location = $shell.namespace($SavePath)
            foreach ($ZipFile in $ZipFileNames) {
                $ZipFolder = $shell.namespace($ZipFile)
                $Location.Copyhere($ZipFolder.items())
                Remove-item $ZipFile
            }
        }
        Catch {
            Send-ErrorReport -Subject "Attachment save path cannot be accessed" -body "Please verify the following path <B>$SavePath</B><BR>Full Error:<BR> $_" -HaltScript
            }
        }
   }
}
$strFileName=($SavePath + "\\" + $FileName)
If (Test-Path $strFileName){
    If ((Get-Content $strFileName) -eq "") {
        "File Exists and is empty"; exit 1
}Else{
        "File Exists and is stable."
}
}Else{
  "File Does Not Exist"; exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your `$filename` variable is empty, it should be declared before you can put it in your If statement, declare it before like this:

```
$EmailwithAttachments = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage]::Bind($service, $Email.Id, $emailProps)
    $Filename = MyFileName
        Foreach ($File in $EmailwithAttachments.Attachments) {
        If ($File.name -eq $FileName)
```

Comment: The code is part of a larger chunk and works properly I just need to have that Write-Host if file is empty.

Comment: What type of file is? .log, .txt, .csv?

Comment: file can be one of many different attachments. $FileName could be file.txt or file.csv or file.xls, etc.